# Cant Call Column

Tags: python, pandas

I uploaded UK housing index' data and heres the code for importing,

```
ukhindex = pd.read_csv('ukhindex.csv')

ukhindex.head()
```

It returns this table:

[image]

However when I try to call the Index column,

```
ukhindex["Date"].head()
```

It gives me this error instead.

[image]

Here some addition details about my table.

[image]

Can someone please help.

Comment: Date is not a column, it is a level of the index. If you want it to be a column, do `uhxindex = uhxindex.reset_index()` (or don't specify an `index_col` when reading in the CSV).

Comment: @Marius, made the changes. Still doesnt recognize the index column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it wasnt picking the column but I just referenced it through column number.

```
ukhindex.iloc[1:10,4]
```

it works fine...

Edit : Turns out on the original CSV file each of the colomn headers had a space at the end before the comma. Thats why it wasnt picking them up...